# .NET application cannot open web folder on another server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I'm trying to search through folders that are publicly accessible on another server but my application keeps getting the following error:

> Message :Unable to connect to the remote server
>   StackTrace :   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at commissioners_decisions._Default.uiSearchTermButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\websites92\MainSite92\commissioner_decisions\Default.aspx.cs:line 500
>   Date :6/19/2017 9:59:52 AM....061[2]R6180

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the IIS permissions but I'm not sure what to give permissions to on the folders.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
bool found = false;
Spire.Doc.Documents.TextSelection ts = null;
Stream stream = null;
MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream();
HttpWebRequest docRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse docResponse = (HttpWebResponse)docRequest.GetResponse();
stream = docResponse.GetResponseStream();
stream.CopyTo(stream2);
stream2.Position = 0;
Spire.Doc.Document document = new Spire.Doc.Document();
document.LoadFromStream(stream2, FileFormat.Auto);
ts = document.FindString(txtBasicSearch.Text, false, true);
if (ts != null)
{
     found = true;
}
if (found)
{
     hearingArrayList.Add(h);
     foundCount++;
}
```

Comment: can you show us the code?

Comment: Do you try to read from a network share?

Comment: Are these servers on the same domain? That makes this setup easier.

Comment: Same domain but I don't know if they're on the same vlan, it's not from a network share, but I could set it up that way if it's easier

Comment: Using RunAs, open an instance of IE as the user under which your program runs (e.g. its service account) and paste the url into the address bar. What do you get back?